# How to install dfc package in Debian Jessie

Tags: disk-usage

The nice disk-usage tool `dfc` does not exist in Debian jessie, although it does in wheezy and stretch.

How do I install it in Debian 8?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install it from stretch, add the debian 8 sources:

```
echo "deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages    stretch main contrib non-free
deb http://http.debian.net/debian               stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch.list
```

and pin them lower than all jessie sources with

```
echo "Package:  *
Pin:  release n=jessie-updates
Pin-Priority:  500

Package:  *
Pin:  release n=jessie
Pin-Priority:  500

Package:  *
Pin:  release n=stretch-updates
Pin-Priority:  499

Package:  *
Pin:  release n=stretch
Pin-Priority:  499
" > /etc/apt/preferences.d/stretch-manual-only
```

Now you can install it with

```
apt-get update
apt-get install dfc
```